# undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller create method like this.

```
def create  
  if user.save!
    user.add_role = params[:user][:Role].parameterize('_').to_sym
    if current_user.has_role?(:producer_or_beat_maker_or_composer)
      #if(Student.find_by_email("#{current_user.email}")!= nil)
      redirect_to(:controller => 'users',:action => new_registration_path(resource_name))
    elsif  current_user.role=="Producer"
      redirect_to(:controller => 'users',:action => 'index')
    end
  end
end
```

when i click on user creation,i got an error like " undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass". please help through this..

Comment: can you please add `request log`?

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite simple `params[:user][:Role]` is `nil`. Perhaps you meant `params[:user][:role]`.

Comment: @mohdazmath why don't you follow naming conventions?